# Django forms dynamic getting author as a logged in user in model forms

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I'm trying to make some forms that will allow users to add some objects, delete them or edit but I've stucked with thing like author of model. Let's say we got model Shot which got field

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Because I've created custom user model to expand user by some fields that I want, and then we creating modelForm, creating views etc. and finally got form. When we will try to submit this form, it won't add this object submited in form to db because form has no filled field author author which means this field == Null and that's why it won't add this to db. So my question is how to get it dynamic, for example when user with nick "thebestuser" will try to add this modelForm it will work and mark author as "thebestuser"? Ofc I could add to form field author, but it's the worst way in my opinion and every user would be allowed then to add object for example as a another user, let's say user with nick "anothernick" could add form as a user with "thebestuser" which is In my opinion not acceptable.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from streamers.models import Streamer
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone


class Shot(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    streamer = models.ForeignKey(Streamer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Shot

class AddShot(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shot
        fields = [
            'title',
            'url',
            'streamer',
        ]
```

```py
views.py
@login_required
def add_shot(request):
    form = AddShot(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.published_date = request.published_date
        instance.author = request.user
        instance.save()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'shots/add_shot.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do it in your view. When you save your form pass `commit=False` to your save method, add your user, then save the returned instance.

```
def my_view(request):
  form = AddShot(request.POST)
  instance = form.save(commit=False)
  instance.author = request.user
  instance.save()
```

Documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Thank you, but 1 question is it gonna work with custom user model? I've forgot to add in question, I've created custom users model (I had to expand basic user model by few fields)

Comment: Yes, it'll work with a custom user model. The `auth` package handles all that in middleware.

Comment: Hey, I've edited question and added view because I'm having no results, when I submit form it just redirect me but not adding to DB so I guess it's syntax wrong. Please take a look

Comment: It's probably your first `form.save()`. When you first save the form you don't want it to commit to the database, so you pass `commit=False`. Also you probably want to be checking if you're sending a POST request instead of passing `None` to your form.