# How to auto detect user in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How To Detect User In Django! i see the most of people use foreign key but i don't want foreign key i want to detect user without foreign key i want to detect which user fill this form for example test or something

Here is my `views.py`

```
def buy_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usr_buy = user_buy_form(request.POST)
        if usr_buy.is_valid():
            usr_buys = usr_buy.save(commit=False)
            usr_buys.save()
        else:
            return print(usr_buy.errors)

    else:
        usr_buy = user_buy_form()

    context = {'usr_buy':usr_buy}

    return render(request,'user_buy.html',context)
```

Here is my `models.py`

```
class user_register_model(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class user_buy(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(user_register_model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    Trade_limits = models.IntegerField()
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.users.user.username
```

Here is my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Buy_List_View.as_view(),name='index'),
    path('accounts/signup/', views.user_reg,name='register'),
    path('profile/<username>', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
    path('sell_btc/',views.buy_form,name='buy_form')
]
```

Here is my `user_buy.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
<form class="form-control" method="POST">
    {{usr_buy.as_p}}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my `forms.py`

```
class user_buy_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = user_buy
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django forms dynamic getting author as a logged in user in model forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352836/django-forms-dynamic-getting-author-as-a-logged-in-user-in-model-forms)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using **django signal handlers**, 
you can get a signal by registering what you want to watch and when you want to watch.

In your example,
**What to watch?**

- User table (user model)

**When to watch?**

- Either **before saving** incoming data (user in your case) which is
  defined in your 'user' model using 'pre_save' handler.
- Or **after
  saving** the data, using 'post_save' handler.

**How to watch?**

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save

Also, you can enable auditlogs from django to watch what operations are performed.
https://django-auditlog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score -1):

First you should exclude the `users` field from your form:

```
class user_buy_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = user_buy
        exclude = ('users',)
```

Then, before saving your `user_buy` instance, you should add the user to it:

```
def buy_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usr_buy = user_buy_form(request.POST)
        if usr_buy.is_valid():
            usr_buys = usr_buy.save(commit=False)
            usr_buys.users = request.user
            usr_buys.save()
        else:
            return print(usr_buy.errors)

    else:
        usr_buy = user_buy_form()

    context = {'usr_buy':usr_buy}

    return render(request,'user_buy.html',context)
```

#### Edit (based on `user_register_model` model)

Since you have a one-to-one field with django user model, you should look for the `user_register_model` instance based on `request.user`:

```
def buy_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usr_buy = user_buy_form(request.POST)
        if usr_buy.is_valid():
            usr_buys = usr_buy.save(commit=False)
            user_register_obj = user_register_model.objects.get(user=request.user)
            usr_buys.users = user_register_obj
            usr_buys.save()
        else:
            return print(usr_buy.errors)

    else:
        usr_buy = user_buy_form()

    context = {'usr_buy':usr_buy}

    return render(request,'user_buy.html',context)
```

Comment: I get this error `NOT NULL constraint failed: bitcoin_user_buy.users_id`

Comment: That's because you are not logged-in. So `request.user` will return `null` and you get this error. If you want to permit anonymous users to fill the form, you should set `blank=True` and `null=True` in your model. If you don't, add `if request.user.is_authenticated` before saving the form.

Comment: Are you using django's user model (`django.contrib.auth`) or extending it?

Comment: i'm using django login system

Comment: Please show me the `user_register_model` model code (the foreign key model).

Comment: Question Updated!

Comment: i getting this error `user_register_model matching query does not exist.`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with your models, I tested the solution and that works fine for me.